# Really simple Django query

Tags: mysql, django

I want to save in aux this query

```
select id from principal_dep where dep_name='Field';
```

the user selects the field in a form. I have this which is obviously wrong

```
aux = Dep.objects.filter(id=request.POST['dept'])
```

how can I do this?, help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
dep = Dep.objects.get(dep_name=request.POST['dept'])
dep_id = dep.id
```

or

```
dep_ids = Dep.objects.filter(dep_name=request.POST['dept']).values_list('id', flat=True)
```

Comment: Thank you. Again, I didn't meant to be repetitive but I was out of time

Comment: Note that while correct, this will throw an exception if more than one row has that value for `dep_name`. To avoid that, use `filter` instead of `get` and test the size of the resulting qs (either using `.count()` or `len` depending on the exact situation). Or catch the exception.